# How to remove java.io.IOException: Stream closed?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send an SMS through an API but it is showing the error
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
Here is the code I am using:

```
package com.pyprestaurants;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class SendMessage extends Thread {
    String message;
    String number;

    SendMessage(String message, String number){
        this.message = message;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Construct data
            String apiKey = "apikey=" + "nZ0ZOkGeO3U-lkmMqZZuUgKmjjrpCf6v3WMoBV3jWG";
            String message = "&message=" + this.message;
            String sender = "&sender=" + "PYPRES";
            String numbers = "&numbers=" + this.number;

            // Send data
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new 
            URL("https://api.textlocal.in/send/?").openConnection();
            String data = apiKey + numbers + message + sender;
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.length()));
            conn.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            rd.close();
            String line;
            String msg="";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                 msg = msg+line;
                 Log.d("TAG","the message is "+line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TAG- Error msg ",e+"");
        }
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
}
```

I have various activities through which I want to send the SMS. Therefore I have made one separate class which is using thread. Whenever I want to send the message I use to call the function of the SendMessage class(whose code is given above). Now the problem is in some activities it is sending a message but is some case it is showing the error:

> java.io.IOException: Stream closed

I am highly confused that how come the same code can run once while the other time it shows an error.
If someone knows what's the error please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are calling rd.readLine()) after rd.close();.
Try to move the rd.close() method further back so all calls to rd are done before you close it.

Answer (score 0):

Your closing your inputstream before reading it

```
        InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        rd.close();
        String line;
```